# Calculating users share of a growing pool

Tags: solidity

Let’s say you have two pools,
The pool_1 is only growing with new users entering. It is earning rewards which are then put in a second pool_2 which then grows by auto compounding. New users enter the pool all the time. The users should be able to withdraw either their share of pool_1 , pool_2 or both.

How would you calculate each users share of the pool_2?

The thing I can’t come up with a simple solution for is, when a new user enters, I can’t give him a share of the existing pool_2. It would need some mechanism that factors in when this user entered the pool, so the program knows from when it should start including the new user in the growing rewards pool_2.

Maybe I’m looking at this the wrong way, let me know what you think!

Comment: You should probably store a timestamp when the user enters. Compare that to the pool start timestamp, and calculate the ratio compared to other stakers

Comment: so if a user wants to withdraw (`wUser`), wouldnt I have to find out all users who has staked since `wUser` entered until he withdraws, and being able to check the erc20 balance of the staking contract on every instance of an initial stake? I think I'm overcomplicating things and I cant really find any other contracts who are doing this. They usually just grow the initial pool or give out rewards by minting new tokens, maybe you know of any contract I could look at?

Comment: Sorry, not aware of any specific contracts. Yes, it will easily get complicated. The trick is to think of a data structure which doesn't require much looping.

Comment: Yea, or if the pool has 2 stakers, I would need to figure out a way to give the third new user a `share` that is worth 0 of the pool so far but 1/3 of everything that follows, until a new staker comes and all shares values goes down to 1/4 and so on. Feels like I'm missing some really simple solution to this, kiitos muutenki!

Comment: did you figure it out ?